# Setting up the TypePal type checker on Eclipse IDE

Tags: rascal

After implementing a type checker in Rascal using TypePal, how do I hook it up to the Eclipse IDE? Any resources or repositories to the solution to this problem would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- in Eclipse `search path` of the Rascal Navigator view in your project you will find the `rascal_eclipse` library which contains a good example:  `demo::lang::Pico::Plugin`
- in this module you see how to register a language with Eclipse:
  `registerLanguage("Pico Language", "pico", parsePico);` where parsePico is a function reference. Pass your own parameters here. The registerLanguage function comes from `util::IDE`.
- now you can open files with the "IMP editor" in Eclipse and they will use your parser and show syntax highlighting.
- next up is registering other effects with the IDE. The library function to call is `registerAnnotator`. You pass it a function that takes a parse tree for your language and annotates it with error messages:

  - the messages may be distributed over the tree, using `@message` or
  - using a list of `@messages` at the top of the tree
- the error messages will be added as annotations in the editor and registered with the Problem View automatically.

So you have to wire the output of TypePal into the annotator function yourself. Which should be a one-liner.

Alternatively, running type-checks can also be useful after a "save" action. In this case you can register another type of contribition (also in the Pico demo), called `builder`: builder(set[Message] ((&T<:Tree) tree) messages), and register that with the `registerContributions` function.

The `Message` ADT is the same for the annotator and the builder. Both have the effect of adding editor annotations and problems in the view.

Here is some example code taken from an older open-source DSL project called "Bird", https://github.com/SWAT-engineering/bird:

```
Tree checkBird(Tree input){
    model = birdTModelFromTree(input, pathConf = config(input@\loc)); // your function that collects & solves
    types = getFacts(model);
  
  return input[@messages={*getMessages(model)}]
              [@hyperlinks=getUseDef(model)]
              [@docs=(l:"<prettyPrintAType(types[l])>" | l <- types)]
         ; 
}
```

- `birdTModelFromTree` calls `collectAndSolve` from TypePal and returns the `TModel`
- `getMessage` comes from TypePal's Utilities and extracts a `list[Message]` from the `TModel` that can be directly communicated to Eclipse via the `@messages` annotation.
- The entire `checkBird` function is registered as an `annotator` using the `util::IDE` function `registerAnnotator`.
- This code hasn't been used for a while, so if you run into trouble, please contact again?

Comment: Thanks @jurgen; is there any example repository to follow up this instructions for clarity purposes?

Comment: Hi Pius, only demo::lang::Pico::Plugin as far as I know. The other repositories are proprietarty of swat.engineering. I'll ask if they have some code examples.

Comment: Thanks sir, I would be waiting on it?

Comment: Hi Jurgen, I’ve gone through the code for demo::lang::Pico::Plugin
I still haven’t figured out the function signature of registerAnnotator.
In the Pico snippet below:

public void registerPico() {
  registerLanguage(Pico_NAME, Pico_EXT, parsePico);
  registerAnnotator(Pico_NAME, checkPicoProgram);
  registerContributions(Pico_NAME, Pico_CONTRIBS);
}

How do I write a checkPicoProgram that uses my Typepal type checker?
I understand what Pico_NAME does.

Comment: I'm currently unavailable. Next week I'm back and we can work together on a comprehensive answer. The annotator should take a parse tree of a file as parameter and call typepal and then get the error messages out of the tmodel and return them.

Comment: Thanks @jurgen; I would ping you then, in the mean time I would keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hi @jurgen; I am still in need of the comprehensive answer on how to wire up TypePal on Eclipse IDE, I am still unable to figure it out yet, thanks.

Comment: I added some example code to the answer. Hope that works. I don't have a working Eclipse environment at the moment. Thanks for your patience Pius.

Comment: Thanks @jurgen; I have been able to wire up the TypePal on the Eclipse IDE, the information you provided was very helpful. I have some questions on the error message reporting in TypePal. How do I customise the semantic error message (in the case of a reference to a none existing fact)? How do I report warning using TypePal?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to marshal a TModel into a Summary, here is my code snippets this could save someone else the pain I went through trying to figure this out.

```
Summary aliasesSummarizer(loc l, start[Program] input) {
pt = parse(#start[Program], l).top;
TModel model = aliasesTModelForTree(input); // TypeChecker called
definitions = model.definitions; 
return summary(l,
    messages = {<message.at, message> | message <- model.messages},
    references = {<definition, definitions[definition].defined> | definition <- definitions}
);};
```